# How to .append a checkbox with value?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, append

I need to append a checkbox which has a value of `value.Project` to my table record but I don’t know the correct syntax.

Part of my function:

```
$.each(data.Records, function(index, value) {
  var record = $('<tr>');
  record.addClass('data');
  record.append($('<td>' +
    value.Date + '</td><td>' +
    value.Client + '</td><td>' +
    '</td><td><a href="@Url.Action("Edit")?id=' + value.Id + '">Edit </a>| '));
  table.append(record);
});
```

I tried this, but it doesn’t work:

```
+ '<input class="check-box" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" value="value.Project"' + '</td><td>'
```

What should it look like?

Comment: `value="value.Project"` <= `value.Project` here is a literal string.  Consider how you are doing that vs how you are doing the `value.Date` appending earlier in your same code.  Why are you appending differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your concatenation of values are not right in the checkbox.

change your code from:

```
+ '<input class="check-box" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" value="value.Project"' + '</td><td>'
```

to

```
+ '<input class="check-box" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" value="'+value.Project+'"> </td><td>'
```

---

If you want the checkbox to be checked add `checked` attribute.

```
+ '<input class="check-box" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" value="'+value.Project+'" checked="'+value.Project+'"> add your label value here</td><td>'
```

Comment: still my checkboxes are all empty, `value.Project` gives me value of true or false so i need checkboxes to be checked or empty

Comment: what do you mean by empty? it doesn't have the value or it doesn't have the label?

Comment: it doesn't have the label, in example value is true but checkbox isnt checked

Comment: value has nothing to do with checked state.  the `checked` attribute, existing or not existing, does [MDN Checkbox checked attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/checkbox#checked)

Comment: If you want the checkbox to be checked you need the `checked` attribute. I updated the code with checked attribute. still you need to append label. You haven't mentioned object key for `label and value` so you need to add that too.

Comment: does your `value.Project` has values? check case-sensitive also.

Comment: The **existance** of the `checked` attribute makes it checked.  Not setting it to true/false.  If you do not want it checked, do not add the `checked` attribute.  But this has really turned into a scope creap problem and is not about the original question.  This should be a new question.

Comment: i have in html`<input class="check-box" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" value="false" checked="false">` so how can i set checked attribute if its true and unchecked if its false?

Comment: Again, **don't add checked at all** if you do not want it checked. [HTML Standards checked attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute) "A number of attributes are boolean attributes. **The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value**, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value."